# Find index of element C#

Tags: c#

I have an string array of months in C# from jan to dec. I want to plug in nov and get 11. How do i do this?

```
 Months.FindIndex("November")+1//returns 11
```

Comment: You want to 'plug in' "nov" or "November"?

Comment: Don't forget C# indices start at 0 so in an array (or list) of months November will occupy the slot with the index 10 not 11.

Comment: @ChrisF - I guess that is why he adds + 1 in his example code.

Comment: @Øyvind - I thought he might want to avoid the +1 somehow

Comment: @ChrisF - I thought that he only tried to find out how to actually do the `FindIndex`part (and I still do) :)

Comment: @Øyvind - you're probably right.

Comment: @Øyvind Bråthen: Yep thats right. Array.IndexOf FTW

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int monthnumber = Array.IndexOf(Months, "November") + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

To do a match based on some predicate you can use `Array.FindIndex`:

```
int num = Array.FindIndex(Months, month => month.StartsWith("nov", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) + 1;
```